# Cannot find signalr/js script file

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, signalr

I'm following a video tutorial on using signalr but I'm getting an error. I've gotten up to this point:
 https://youtu.be/FkwiDZDBf7w?t=3m12s

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and running it in the Microsoft Edge browser. When I go to Console view to view I get the following errors:

1. HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the
   requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier). GET -
   http://localhost:21167/signalr/js
2. SCRIPT5022: SignalR: Error loading hubs. Ensure your hubs reference
   is correct, e.g. .
   jquery.signalR-2.2.2.min.js (9,5392)

My index.cshtml uses (as per the video tutorial):

But googling for the problem reveals multiple solutions. I've tried all of these but none work:

1. `<script src="/signalr/js"></script>`
2. `<script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>`
3. `<script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>`

The tutorial says that the signmalr/js folder is autogenerated but how and when is this autogenerated?

Any ideas on how to correct the issue?

Comment: your signalr hub probably hasn't started either you may haven't configured it properly.

Check the console since in the video at 2:12 you should be writing to console if the hub has started or hasn't

Comment: @csharpwinphonexaml thank you, you were right. I was missing the startup.cs file, in the tutorial video it seemed to have been added by default (which it didn't do in my project). It all worked fine when I manually added it. Thank you

Comment: Write an answer or close the question please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was given by csharpwinphonexaml via a comment. I was missing the startup.cs file, in the tutorial video it seemed to have been added by default (which it didn't do in my project). It all worked fine when I manually added it.